# What is the pattern that UIKit uses to figure out the right nib name to load?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have a weird question:
What is the pattern that the `UIKit` is using to figure out the right nib name for a  `UIViewController`, when you don't explicitly specify the `nibName`?

Why am I asking?

Because I thought (With a good reason) that the system will first look for the nib with the same name as the controller's class's.
That is, if I have a `VideoViewController`, the system will first look for `VideoViewController.xib`.

Apparently this is not the case.
I have another class, `VideoView`, which is a subclass of `UIView`. I have a nib called `VideoView.xib` that contains all the view hierarchy for `VideoView`.

When I try to run the app, it crashes immediately with `setValue:ForUndefinedKey` Exception.
I noticed that the key is always a key from the VideoView.xib, and **not** from `VideoViewController.xib`. That means that the system is trying to load `VideoView.xib` for a view controller named `VideoViewController`.

It seems that if the system will find a nib with a name similar the controller class name -only without the "Controller" suffix, it'll use that nib.

I confirmed it by renaming my class to `VideosViewController` (With 's'), and everything worked just fine.

Are there any more edge conditions like this one?
Or is there a place that specify the exact algorithm?

It took me an hour to debug this one, and I don't want to waste any more time in the future on the same problem...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of *UIViewController.nibName* property:

> If you use a nib file to store your view controller’s view, it is
>   recommended that you specify that nib file explicitly when
>   initializing your view controller. However, if you do not specify a
>   nib name, and do not override the loadView method in your custom
>   subclass, the view controller searches for a nib file using other
>   means. Specifically, it looks for a nib file with an appropriate name
>   (without the .nib extension) and loads that nib file whenever its view
>   is requested. Specifically, it looks (in order) for a nib file with
>   one of the following names:
>
> 1. If the view controller class name ends with the word “Controller”, as
>      in MyViewController, it looks for a nib file whose name matches the
>      class name without the word “Controller”, as in MyView.nib.
> 2. It looks
>      for a nib file whose name matches the name of the view controller
>      class. For example, if the class name is MyViewController, it looks
>      for a MyViewController.nib file.

Comment: Oh jesus... I read all the documentation except this property.. I looked at view, loadView etc... Thanks!